# To proof the difference images is a subset of their map difference sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Let $A$ and $B$ sets, with $P,Q \subseteq A$ and let $f:A \to B$

1) prove that $f(P)-f(Q) \subseteq  f(P-Q)$

2)Is it necessarily the case that $f(P-Q) \subseteq f(P)-f(Q)$? Give a proof or a counterexample

How I can to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Is quite straight forward: Let $b \in f[P] - f[Q]$.Then $b \in f[P]$, $b \not\in f[Q]$. By definition of $f[P]$, there is an $p \in P$ with $b = f(p)$. As $b \not\in f[Q]$, $p \not\in Q$. Hence $p \in P - Q$ and therefore $b \in f[P-Q]$.

Hint for (2). Think of constant functions, let for example $A = B = \mathbf R$ and let $f$ be a constant functions.